# Generate Set of Integers through HashSet using Java Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I was trying to create a HashSet by get all keys of a HashMap whose values are greater than 0. To do so, i considered Java Streams, something with Collectors, but without success. The only way i got success was using a forEach loop with an if statement inside, described in the code below:

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> profiencyOnSkill;
HashSet<Integer> skills;

profiencyOnSkill.put(1, 0.5);
profiencyOnSkill.put(2, 0.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(3, 1.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(4, 0.02);
profiencyOnSkill.put(5, 0.0);

profiencyOnSkill
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .forEach(pair -> {
                if (pair.getValue() > 0.0) {
                    skills.add(pair.getKey());
                }
            });

skills.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is there any direct way to do with Collectors? All my ideas with Collectors returned a `Map.Entry<Integer, Double>`. Something like that:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>> someSet = proficiencyOnSkill.entrySet().stream().filter(x-> x.getValue() == 2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: *I was trying to create a HashSet by get all **entries** of a HashMap whose values are greater than 0.* Do you mean keys? If so, just add a `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` before collecting.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, the correct is keys, as you pointed. Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please initialize your types so your code is runnable. Anyway, yes you can `filter` on your criteria then `map` on the `Entry.key` and collect to a `Set` like

```
Map<Integer, Double> profiencyOnSkill = new HashMap<>();

profiencyOnSkill.put(1, 0.5);
profiencyOnSkill.put(2, 0.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(3, 1.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(4, 0.02);
profiencyOnSkill.put(5, 0.0);
Set<Integer> skills = profiencyOnSkill.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(pair -> pair.getValue() > 0)
        .map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And you could (but don't have to) just print `skills`.

```
System.out.println(skills);
```

I get

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. A question arises now. I was thinking if this is more efficient than rather just iterate through the HashSet and seeing if the condition (value greater than 0) was satisfied and add to the Set. Maybe they have the same complexity?

Comment: @JoséJoaquim Same complexity, but (in theory) you could make this a `parallelStream()` and gain some additional improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you don’t need the original mappings afterwards, you can also do

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> profiencyOnSkill = …;
profiencyOnSkill.values().removeIf(v -> v<=0);
Set<Integer> skills = profiencyOnSkill.keys();

skills.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> profiencyOnSkill = new HashMap<>();
HashSet<Integer> skills = new HashSet<>();

profiencyOnSkill.put(1, 0.5);
profiencyOnSkill.put(2, 0.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(3, 1.0);
profiencyOnSkill.put(4, 0.02);
profiencyOnSkill.put(5, 0.0);

// To get both key and value
HashSet<Entry<Integer, Double>> hs = profiencyOnSkill.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
System.out.println(hs);

// To get only keys
skills = profiencyOnSkill.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 0).map(Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

System.out.println(skills);
```

Comment: An alternative for the first result: `hs = new HashSet<>(profiencyOnSkill.entrySet()); hs.removeIf(e -> e.getValue() <= 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version that doesn't make use of streams:

```
Set<Integer> skills = new HashSet<>();
profiencyOnSkill.forEach((k, v) -> { if (v > 0.0) skills.add(k); });
```

Which is no more than an improved version of your original code.